# is there an elegant way to extract the words from this array ["{ test1, test2 }", "test3", "{test4, test5}"], and put them together inside one array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

Basically I want turn the array from

```
["{ test1, test2 }", "test3", "{test4, test5}"]
```

to

```
["test1","test2","test3","test4","test5"]
```

I'm using regex, matchTest being the variable holding the regex, to match words and populating this array with the matches, and also fixing the array in the same loop.

```
 while (regexMatches = matchTest.exec(sourceCode)) {
   testArray.push(regexMatches[1].replace(/\W/g, " ").split(" "));
   testArray = [].concat(...testArray);
   testArray = testArray.filter(testArray => testArray != '');
 }
```

The way I'm doing it works, but it seems quite messy. Any help on how to improve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var array = ["{ test1, test2 }", "test3", "{test4, test5}"];
var output = array.join(',').replace(/[^\w,]/g,'').split(',');
```

Comment: Actually this /[^\w,]/g was from your solution, hehe

Answer (score 3):

I'd use `.reduce()` as follows:

```js
var input = ["{ test1, test2 }", "test3", "{test4, test5}"]

var output = input.reduce((acc, v) => {
  acc.push(...v.replace(/[^\w,]/g,"").split(","))
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(output)
```

That is, for each item in the array, first remove all characters that aren't word characters or commas, then split on commas, then push the results into the output array.

Answer (score 0):

you should put `match`

```js
var string = '["{ test1, test2 }", "test3", "{test4, test5}"]';
var array = string.match(/\w+\d+/g);
console.log(array);
```